# Understand endless loop in Linked-list algorithm named "Partition"

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am trying to solve the problem "2.4 Partition" from the book "Cracking the coding interview" :
  Problem: Given a linked list and a value x, partition it such that all nodes
 less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x.

Somehow it goes into endless loop. The solution from the book is slightly different from mine (book solution commented). I am trying to understand why the solution from the book is working and mine does not.

```
public static Node particion(Node node, int x) {

    Node beforeStart = null;
    Node beforeEnd = null;
    Node afterStart = null;
    Node afterEnd = null;

    while (node != null) {

//      Node next = node.next;

//      node.next = null;

        if (node.data < x) {
            if(beforeStart == null) {
                beforeStart = node;
                beforeEnd = beforeStart;
            } else {
                beforeEnd.next = node;
                beforeEnd = node;
            }
        } else {
            if(afterStart == null) {
                afterStart = node;
                afterEnd = afterStart;
            } else {
                afterEnd.next = node;
                afterEnd = node;
            }
        }
//      node = next;

        node = node.next;
    }

    if(beforeStart == null) {
        return afterStart;
    }

    beforeEnd.next = afterStart;
    return beforeStart;
}
```

input:3 5 8 5 10 2 1 (partition = 5)
output: 3 2 1 5 8 5 10

instead, my endless output is :
3 2 1 5 8 5 10 2 1 5 8 5 10 2 1 5 8 5 10 2 1 5 8 5 10 (etc. )

Comment: Where in your code does node.next() return null?

Comment: You should set node.next to null for it to not go in infinite loop

Comment: That's a case for using the debugger and step through your program.